# Two-Dimensional Array with Loops Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to accomplish the following in a for loop:

For every number within 256, 0 between 256 inclusive, I want to store every iteration of 4 into each row. Then increment the column and insert next iteration of 4 into each row....and so forth.

I wrote it in C...

```
int matrix[4][64];
int rowCount = 0;
int colCount = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++){
  if(rowCount < 4){
    matrix[rowCount][colCount] = i
    rowCount++;
  }

  if(rowCount == 4){
    colCount++;
    rowCount = 0;
  }
}
```

How could I accomplish the same thing in Javascript?

Comment: Take a course in JavaScript programming.

Comment: You should probably take a course in [tag:c] too.

Comment: You didn't wrote it in C. 256 is excluded in the range in your program.

Comment: I guess what you want to do is to "partition" an array containing values from 0 to 256 into subarrays of length 4, right? In that case, you can find a solution by googling "partition array javascript".

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code I think this is what you are getting at...
`[[0,1,2,3],...,[252,253,254,255]]`

```
var array = [];

for(i=0;i<256;i+=4){
    array.push([i,i+1,i+2,i+3]);
}
```